# Running gulp tasks in sibling folder

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, gulp

Let's say I need to run a gulp command to build some assets.

Assume I am at root folder, I have a dir called ./node_modules/semantic-ui/, that requires to run 'gulp build' to get necessary assets.

I also setup an npm command, called

```
build:semantic': 'gulp ./node_modules/semantic-ui'
```

but it is not possible to do so and I am not willing to use cd command inside my npm run command.

What can I do to do so? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gulp allows you to pass a **--cwd** and if you do that it will run from within that directory. So in your case, you do this:

```
gulp --cwd './node_modules/semantic-ui'
```

Hope that helps. Let me know if it doesn't.